# generate union sqls based on parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write sql which would take parameters and based on parameters
create a view with union of parameter tables

currently I am doing below but customer tables range from R1 to R40

```
create or replace view customers_a as 
select * from customer_R1 
UNION 
select *  from customer_R40;
```

now what I need is to write sql that will take params as

```
@gen.sql R1 R3 R4
```

and create view as

```
create or replace view customers_ALL as 
select * from customer_R1 
UNION 
select *  from customer_R3
UNION 
select *  from customer_R4;
```

depending on parameters passed , it should be dynamic

Comment: Replaced the `plsql` tag with `oracle` as no PL/SQL is involved here. Btw: this sounds like a horrible data model. Why do you have so many customer tables in the first place? That should be only a single table (possibly partitioned)

Comment: i added plsql as answers could be in plsql , and customer table is just an example

Comment: Why would want a stored procedure? Just fix your data model and then you don't need anything like that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered this?

```
create or replace view customers_ALL as 
    select 'R1' as which, c.* from customer_R1 c
    UNION ALL
    select 'R2' as which, c.* from customer_R1 c
    UNION ALL
    select 'R3', c.* from customer_R3 c
    UNION ALL
    . . .
    select 'R31', *  from customer_R31 c;
```

Then you can just query this view using:

```
select *
from customers_ALL
where which in ('R1', 'R3', 'R4')
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates among the tables.  Otherwise, the introduction of `which` will make the rows unique (which is why I changed `union` to `union all`).

Comment: I dont have option to create view over all the tables , I need to process it as parameters

Comment: Originally you wrote: "I want to [...] create a view with union of [...]". You are saying that you want to create a view, yet you can't create view over all tables. Please, explain what options you actlaly have.